# Why do I get NullReferenceException in the following code, C#?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, thread-static

I have the following test program where I an using a `ThreadStatic` variable, when I try this code I get a `NullReferenceException` .

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MiscTests
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static Person _person = new Person { Name = "Jumbo" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(TestThread);
            t1.Start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(TestThread1);
            t2.Start();         
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TestThread(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("before: " + _person.Name);
            _person.Name = "TestThread";
            Console.WriteLine("after: " + _person.Name);
        }

        private static void TestThread1(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("before: " + _person.Name);
            _person.Name = "TestThread1";
            Console.WriteLine("after: " + _person.Name);
        }       
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain it please ?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: NullReferenceException errors are always caused by the same thing: you're trying to dereference an object variable that contains `null`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: In this case, the cause is more subtle.

Comment: @SLaks: You mean he's not trying to dereference an object variable that contains null?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: He is trying to dereference an object which (1) has a non-null initializer in its declaration and (2) is never explicitly assigned to. Under normal circumstances (i.e., without `ThreadStatic`), that combination would never lead to a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 2):

The initializer of a `[ThreadStatic]` variable will only run once, on the thread that initializes the type.

All other threads will see `null`.

Comment: You would think that someone using `[ThreadStatic]` would already know this.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistaked you've declared _person as **ThreadStatic**, which means that the second thread that your running wont have access to it, and it will be therefore null.